# Premiere Pro export same file size as import

Tags: video, premiere, file-formats, export, output

I just want to export a video at the exact same settings as the imported file.

'match source' and 'match sequence settings' do not work. (Adobe Premiere Pro)

On my timeline all I did was trimmed some footage off the beginning and end (so the file should now be smaller!), and the best I can get it is almost twice the size (megabytes) with a huge reduction in quality.

No one can answer this on other threads - It's always "reduce the bitrate" or something, but that makes the quality WORSE than the original file and still ADDS file size!

Comment: additional info: ive imported an mp4 file and am trying to export as mp4 (H.264)

Comment: A shot in the dark: is the bitrate setting showing CBR? If so, try VBR. If this doesn't help, please edit your question and add all the export settings (maybe screenshots). And what codec was the input? MP4 is only a container, there can be anything in there. Is the source also h264 like the codec you chose for export?